# Optimise sapply-grepl on a large dataset

Tags: r, regex, grepl

I have a large data set (df) ~250.000 observations that includes a column cleanText (which contains text cleaned form any numbers, punctiations, capitals, etc.) and I have a list of company names. I want to check each observation in df$cleanText for a match with a company in the list with company names and count the amount of matches it finds and store it. My code works, however, it takes about 20 hours to execute and I feel like it could be a lot faster.

So far I haven't been able to figure out what would work.

```
# Start for loop for each row in df
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){

# store matches in companyNameMatch, make sure the paste0 includes \\b to match whole strings
companyNameMatch <- sapply(list_Companies, function(x) grepl(paste0(x, "\\b"), as.character(df$cleanText[i])))

# Calculate the number of matches and store it
df$companyNameMatch[i] <- as.numeric(length(which(companyNameMatch != 0)))
}
```

I would expect that the code should be able to run within a few hours or so.

EXAMPLE

```
cleanText <- c("keeping a cool head takes practice nike",
               "playing soccer on these adidas",
               "just having a laugh",
               "nike and adidas perform better than crocs")

list_Companies <- c("nike", "adidas", "crocs", "puma")
```

For each row in df$cleanText the sapply function should check whether there is a match with a row from list_Companies. The result in this case looks accordingly:

```
df$companyNameMatch[1] = 1
df$companyNameMatch[2] = 1
df$companyNameMatch[3] = 0
df$companyNameMatch[4] = 3
```

Comment: Please share a minimal reproducible example and show expected output.

Comment: added a short example

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sapply` with `rowSums`

```
df$companyNameMatch <- rowSums(sapply(list_Companies, function(x) grepl(x, cleanText)))
```

Using the `microbenchmark`-package we can see that this clearly improves the speed:

```
Unit: microseconds
     expr      min       lq      mean   median       uq        max neval cld
  rowSums   65.382   78.496   132.345   93.511   119.55   1462.727   100  a 
 for_loop 6206.326 6920.394 11170.353 7340.814 10058.53 170440.373   100   b
```

Comment: substituting "x" with grepl(paste0(x, "\\b"), did the trick for me and clearly seems a lot faster indeed! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With `base R`, we can loop over the'listCompanies, use `grepl` and `Reduce` the `list` of logical vectors into one

```
Reduce(`+`, lapply(list_Companies, grepl, cleanText))
#[1] 1 1 0 3
```

---

Or similar option with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
map(list_Companies, str_detect, string = cleanText) %>% 
           reduce(`+`)
```

Comment: The reduce one seems to work perfectly as well, thanks a lot!